# How to convert pdf to jpeg and retain file size using python

Tags: python, image, pdf, jpeg

I have a one page 30KB PDF.
When I convert it to an image with default settings, the jpeg file is 486KB.

If I set the quality to 10, I can cut the size to 155KB but it's still significantly larger than the original PDF.

I am under the impression that a jpeg is usually smaller in file size than a pdf.

It's not a huge problem with just a few PDFs but converting thousands would require 5 or 6 times the disk space.

Is it possible to convert a PDF to JPEG and keep the file size at least the same without destroying the quality of the image?

Thanks

I'm using python 3.6 on Windows 10

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path

poppler_path = r"C:\poppler-21.03.0\Library\bin"
images = convert_from_path(r'C:\test.pdf', poppler_path=poppler_path)
for image in images:
    image.save('out.jpg', 'JPEG', optimize=True, quality=10)
```

Comment: The problem is, saving bitmap data occupies much more than just text or vector images data
So, if your PDF has lots of text, it inevitably will occupy considerable more as an image